# Carburetor needle broken

Tags: carburetor, opel

I'm new here!

I have an old Opel Kadett KJ 1938 and this part of the carburetor broke:

[image]

I think it's supposed to be the needle or the float valve. You can see clearly that this part is broken. How could I fix this?

EDIT (by Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2):

In case anyone is wondering, this is what it should look like regularly:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

That is the top of the float bowl.. there should be like a triangular shaped cap and I assume seal on there with a bolt or filler type jet going through the centre holding it in place. You could try a bolt with the same thread, but you'll have to find an alternative way of sealing it without that cap. And this is assuming it's not some special fluted bolt etc.

I could only find this weird video of the same type of carb.. but it does show what fits there a bit more clearly.

https://youtu.be/9w2ywsjwtRs

Comment: Yes, a Opel P4. I think both of the cars has the same engine. I could replace this part of the carburetor, but the problem is where to find another carburetor like this. The car is in a mechanic workshop, but it doesn't seem they are competent to handle this (due it's age).

Comment: It that bolt and cap don't actually control fuel flow (I'm not sure you see) or control float height, you could likely just plug and see what effect it has. As I say though if it's some sort of fuel/float control your going to need the correct part, or have one machined.

Comment: Why don't you source a simple carburettor from a similar sized engine and make some adaptor plates to make it fit? Or, are you trying for a "factory standard" re-build?

Comment: @Orb "It that bolt and cap don't actually control fuel flow (I'm not sure you see) or control float height" - I I thought the same thing, but why this part broke?

Comment: @SolarMike, almost 100% of the car is original, so I won't change for a new carburetor and I don't think is necessary to replace for another one.

Comment: @Jazzguy : then you need to repair the damaged thread - evident in your image and the source a replacement for the original part, but, in you original question you asked "how can I fix this" so my response was relevant.

Comment: @Jazzguy... IMHO think it may have just fallen off to be honest as the threads look ok from the bit I can see, and I don't believe a part like the missing lightweight cap would have required much torque at all to keep it in place.